# Setting up / Running tests for modules built on AOSP

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-source, android-make

I am new to AOSP.

We are developing an AOSP C++ middleware module. Currently we have the LOCAL_MODULE setup as the name Foo, with some LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES like Audio, SqliteDatabase, Curl, http client, etc...

I would like to see if it is possible to use googletest to run some unit tests against my code.

I am having issues setup and running the tests. Could anyone give me some guidelines or some examples? (Even a fooDummyTest assert(true) is fine).

1. How do I structure my code?
2. What do I do to run the tests? (make Foo vs make FooTest?)

Any resources or links are welcome,
thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at a module with `BUILD_NATIVE_TEST` variable, for example:

[frameworks/av/camera/tests/Android.mk](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/av/camera/tests/Android.mk)

Also take a look at the files listed in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` you will find examples of Google tests there.

To build the test, go to the directory containing the `Android.mk` and run `mm` (after the correct `lunch` command).

Watch the build output and find the test executable path and push it to the target with `adb push` or use `adb sync` to sync everything. Then connect to the target and run the test by calling the test executable.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up creating a separate module in Android.mk, and have a host libraries compiled on linux. For other libs, I mock the classes.

include $(BUILD_HOST_NATIVE_TEST)